# solr : search query with spaces between words

Tags: solr

I have have a latin plant name like `Chamaecyparis obtusa`
So the result should be all plantnames that starts with Chamaecyparis obtusa

I want to get results like

Chamaecyparis obtusa 'Confucious'
Chamaecyparis obtusa 'Contorta'
Chamaecyparis obtusa 'Coralliformis'
Chamaecyparis obtusa 'Crippsii'

The problem is the space between the words Chamaecyparis and obtusa
For that reson it will not work

I tried it with * and ? but there must be a simple way to do this

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Couple things worth trying from here: [solr query with white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790180/solr-query-with-white-space)

- remove all white space: `Chamaecyparisobtusa`
- use quotes: `"Chamaecyparis obtusa"`
- use parenthesis: `(Chamaecyparis obtusa)`

Additional tips may be found here (check the links also): [Solr Query Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968504/solr-query-syntax)

Comment: Above answer is correct. A small addition - (word1 word2) does not preserve the order of occurance of words in documents, whereas "word1 word2" returns documents that have words in the same order.

Comment: I was already added  quotes but its not search my text is like XXXXX XXXXX XXXX XXXXX XXXX XXXXXX