# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field name

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I am getting above exception in solr search when I try to search something with space.
It works fine if I search without space.

my search query is `package_name:Life Style`

and my schema.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>


<schema name="example core two" version="1.5">
  <types>
   <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
   <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <!-- A Trie based date field for faster date range queries and date faceting. -->
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false"/>
    <!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for exact matching of words -->
    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>



     <!-- A general text field that has reasonable, generic
         cross-language defaults: it tokenizes with StandardTokenizer,
     removes stop words from case-insensitive "stopwords.txt"
     (empty by default), and down cases.  At query time only, it
     also applies synonyms. -->
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_general_standard" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <!-- A text field with defaults appropriate for English: it
         tokenizes with StandardTokenizer, removes English stop words
         (lang/stopwords_en.txt), down cases, protects words from protwords.txt, and
         finally applies Porter's stemming.  The query time analyzer
         also applies synonyms from synonyms.txt. -->
    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
          add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
          analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    -->
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <!-- A text field with defaults appropriate for English, plus
     aggressive word-splitting and autophrase features enabled.
     This field is just like text_en, except it adds
     WordDelimiterFilter to enable splitting and matching of
     words on case-change, alpha numeric boundaries, and
     non-alphanumeric chars.  This means certain compound word
     cases will work, for example query "wi fi" will match
     document "WiFi" or "wi-fi".  However, other cases will still
     not match, for example if the query is "wifi" and the
     document is "wi fi" or if the query is "wi-fi" and the
     document is "wifi".
        -->
    <fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
          add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
          analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>



     <!-- Less flexible matching, but less false matches.  Probably not ideal for product names,
         but may be good for SKUs.  Can insert dashes in the wrong place and still match. -->
    <fieldType name="text_en_splitting_tight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- this filter can remove any duplicate tokens that appear at the same position - sometimes
             possible with WordDelimiterFilter in conjuncton with stemming. -->
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>




     <!-- Just like text_general except it reverses the characters of
     each token, to enable more efficient leading wildcard queries. -->
    <fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
           maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>





    <fieldtype name="payloads" stored="false" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField" >
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!--
        The DelimitedPayloadTokenFilter can put payloads on tokens... for example,
        a token of "foo|1.4"  would be indexed as "foo" with a payload of 1.4f
        Attributes of the DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory : 
         "delimiter" - a one character delimiter. Default is | (pipe)
     "encoder" - how to encode the following value into a playload
        float -> org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads.FloatEncoder,
        integer -> o.a.l.a.p.IntegerEncoder
        identity -> o.a.l.a.p.IdentityEncoder
            Fully Qualified class name implementing PayloadEncoder, Encoder must have a no arg constructor.
         -->
        <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="float"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>


  </types>

  <fieldType name="compositeKeyType" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true"> 
      <analyzer> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> 
        <filter class="solr.ConcatTokenFilterFactory" delim="-"/> 
      </analyzer> 
  </fieldType>

  <fields>   
  <!-- general -->
  <field name="test_package_id"       type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" required="false"/>
  <field name="package_name"       type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
  <field name="code"       type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" required="false"/>
  <field name="from_age"     type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
  <field name="to_age"     type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
  <field name="price"       type="float"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" required="false"/>
  <field name="description"    type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
   <field name="city_id"    type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="false" /> 
<!--  <copyField source="doctor_id" dest="id"/> -->
  </fields>



 <!-- field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. -->



 <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
</schema>
```

Please help me out. what is going wrong here

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your query I would recommend to check the stuff that is already here like

- [solr query with white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790180/solr-query-with-white-space)
  or
- [Solr Query Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968504/solr-query-syntax)